# C# Internal Access Modifier

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I was wondering if anyone could think of a scenario where the following would apply.

```
public class A
{
    private class B
    {
         internal string s { get; set;}
    }
}
```

So I know that internal means that only classes in same assembly have access but in the above case this would not apply because class B is private. I was just curious if this scenario could ever have a use case. By use case I mean is there ever a time to make the access modifier internal inside private class.

Comment: In the code sample you provide, `s` will be accessible inside `A`; there may be a situation where you might want to do something like this. However, this question seems too broad; it depends entirely on the circumstances and I don't think there is a quick answer like "well, in such and such cases you do want to use an internal property inside a private class"

Comment: @Fikolev I disagree. In the above case internal and public would be identical so the reason i posted question is when would there be a time to use internal vs public in the above scenario.

Comment: @Filkolev Example: If you attempted to have a public method inside `A` that returns an instance of `B`, it would give a compile error about returning a more restrictive-access class. Only code inside of `A` should be able to do anything with `B`, and of course code inside of `A` is in the current assembly, so...

Comment: The question should be updated then and it should explicitly ask if there is a reason to make a property internal inside a private class instead of making it public.

Comment: @Fikolev That's exactly what the question asks, or at least that's how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. In C#, partial classes cannot span assemblies, so I can't see a case in which another type definition in the same assembly could have different access to `s` than a type definition in a foreign assembly. Internal is an accessibility modifier applied only at the assembly level so, in this instance, I think `internal` is functionally equivalent to `public`. I'd be delighted to be shown to be wrong, however.

Comment: I agree i couldn't think of a scenario where this would apply.

Answer (score 1):

For the compiler it does not matter. However, for someone else reading or refactoring your code this shows your intention.

If the property is really an assembly detail you might want to keep it internal. This way when someone needs to make the `class B` public for some reason, he wouldn't need to think if this property should be visible, or wouldn't bother to document it. Also, he wouldn't accidentally leave the property public if it is meant to be hidden.

You can think as "What would be the access modifier if this class was public?"

Comment: I like your answer however i feel that if the intention was for the class to be private then the intention was for that class to NOT be public and should create the appropriate access modifier for how it is intended to be now. Upon refactoring it is up to the dev to decide what to change access modifiers to.